# Return json object in controller with placeholder keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working through a node js, express js, and angular js project and the example given for a controller is not how I have it written.  I cannot seem to find any articles explaining the form.

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req,res){
    //your code here
    res.json({placeholder:'index'});
  }
}
```

I understand the res.json is returning the json object, but I'm not familiar with placeholder:'index'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req,res){
    //your code here
    res.json({placeholder:'index'});
  }
}
```

The `{placeholder:'index'}` is what gets returned in the HTTP response. Actually, what gets returned is the string: `{"placeholder":"index"}` - i.e. `{placeholder:'index'}` serialized as JSON. It could be `{hello:'world'}` just as well - it's just an example of what can be returned to the client, and it's up to the client how it will get interpreted.

It seems that in this case different route handlers could have different "placeholders" - like maybe:

```
index: function(req,res){
  res.json({placeholder:'index'});
},
route1: function(req,res){
  res.json({placeholder:'route1'});
},
route2: function(req,res){
  res.json({placeholder:'route2'});
},
```

to see which controller has returned which data, but the `"placeholder"` key in the JSON is nothing more then, well, a placeholder.

Comment: OK... The snippet I have returns a dictionary with a string.  In practice, I would return an actual object... res.json(data) where data contains actual data.